# Foundation Dropdown vertical offset not working

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I cannot make the `vOffset` working in Foundation. I followed [the documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html) but I am failing in this simple task. In foundation we can either specify `data-v-offset` attribute on html or pass `vOffset` to options while initializing.

Fiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/amir734jj/exyy4eLz/

Code for completeness:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button" data-toggle="example-dropdown">Top Aligned</button>

  <div class="dropdown-pane right" id="example-dropdown" data-dropdown>
    Just some junk that needs to be said. Or not. Your choice.
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = new Foundation.Dropdown($("#example-dropdown"), {
    hover: true,
    vOffset: 150
  });

  $("#example-dropdown").foundation();
});
```

---

Update: my final goal is to make the bottom of Dropdown be at the same level as the button (i.e. use `vOffset` by `$("#example-dropdown").height()`)

Comment: can you show the image of your output?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `data-option` attribute like this to achieve the results. Refrence [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html) .

> How to use data-option method in the html:

**1.** To use any attribute just dont use any hyphen and data text in the initializaion.

**2.** To use multiple attributes  use semicolon as separator.

```
<div class="dropdown-pane right" id="example-dropdown" data-dropdown data-options="vOffset:100; hover: true;">
    Just some junk that needs to be said. Or not. Your choice.
  </div>
```

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 15rem;

  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button" data-toggle="example-dropdown">Top Aligned</button>

  <div class="dropdown-pane " id="example-dropdown" data-dropdown data-options="vOffset:100;hOffset:80; hover:true; ">
    Just some junk that needs to be said. Or not. Your choice.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Node.JS Updated my answer .. now you can use both voffset and hoffset to positon it as you want.. the problem was the right class added with the dropdown-pane.. Now its Working in both big and small screen.